ALV Grid: how to process a click on standard toolbar buttons: Insert row and Delete row?
Is there a way to react to a click on the standard ALV Grid tool bar buttons: insert row, delete row, copy row etc. ? It doesn't seem like the backend even reacts to it, is it only handled locally ?
I thought about redefining the CL_GUI_ALV_GRID class to raise an event but clicking on the buttons doesn't even call ABAP code (the debugger isn't braught up).
Surely there is a better way than re-implementing those functions in custom buttons ?

Can't you find any events in this CL_GUI_ALV_GRID that might be good?

No, I've put a breakpoint in most of them. Switching to debug mode before clicking on a button doesn't bring up the debugger, that's why this is probably handled locally ?

The data_changed event triggers when you add a new line and you register the "modified" edit event. If you only registered the "enter" event you have to hit enter after inserting a line. If you can't (or dont want to) register the "modified" event you have to replace the insert button in the toolbar with you own button. Then you can react to it in the "user_command" event.

Thanks ! Any idea on how to trigger an event after moving a row using the row selector ? The ondrop event isn't triggered. Also, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.
